# Проблема инициализации DirectX

Tags: c++, directx

Учусь DirectX по книге "DirectX и С++. Искусство программирования" Фленовa М.Е. Пишу на Visual Studio 2015. Так вот, при попытке инициализации компилятор ругается на FAILED. Ошибка: Flags: необъявленный идентификатор.

Исходный код функции:

```
HRESULT DX3DInit(IDirect3D9** ppiD3D9,
                 IDirect3DDevice9** ppiD3DDevice9,
                 HWND hWnd,
                 DWORD iWidth,
                 DWORD iHeight,
                 BOOL bFullScreen)
{
    if ((*ppiD3D9 = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION)) == NULL)
        return E_FAIL;

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = iWidth;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = iHeight;
    int iRes;

    if (!bFullScreen)
        iRes = MessageBox(hWnd, "Use fullscreen mode?", "Screen",
                          MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION);
    else
        iRes = IDYES;

    if (iRes == IDYES)
    {
        d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_R5G6B5;
        d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_FLIP;
        d3dpp.Windowed = FALSE;
        d3dpp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = D3DPRESENT_RATE_DEFAULT;
        d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_DEFAULT;
    }
    else
    {
        RECT wndRect;
        RECT clientRect;
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &wndRect);
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &clientRect);
        int iWinWidth = iWidth + (wndRect.right - wndRect.left) -
                        (clientRect.right - clientRect.left);
        int iWinHeight = iHeight + (wndRect.bottom - wndRect.top) -
                         (clientRect.bottom - clientRect.top);
        MoveWindow(hWnd, wndRect.left, wndRect.top, iWinWidth, iWinHeight,
                   TRUE);
        D3DDISPLAYMODE d3ddm;
        (*ppiD3D9)->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, &d3ddm);
        d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = d3ddm.Format;
        d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
        d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    }

    DWORD Falgs = D3DCREATE_MIXED_VERTEXPROCESSING |
                  D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED;
    HRESULT hRes;

    if (FAILED(hRes = (*ppiD3D9)->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                      D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd, Flags, &d3dpp, ppiD3DDevice9)))
        return hRes;

    float Aspect = (float)d3dpp.BackBufferWidth / (float)
                   d3dpp.BackBufferHeight;
    D3DXMATRIX matProjection;
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&matProjection, D3DX_PI / 4.0f, Aspect,
                               10.0f, 1000.0f);
    (*ppiD3DDevice9)->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProjection);
    return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну у потому что у Вас объявлена переменная "Falgs" а не "Flags"

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил